# Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php4' in Apache log file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache-2.4

My Apache error log has the same set of error messages regularly. The particular set of error messages total around 17 lines so I've used Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/UfG3vQtn

You will see there is only 3 types of error:

> 1. Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php4'
> 2. Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-cgi'
> 3. [pid=8878 euid=0 egid=99] suexec.cpp(317): setrlimit(2): 2 set to  4294967295/4294967295 (soft/hard) bytes

The server is a 1and1.co.uk Linux managed dedicated server. It runs plain CGI (no Fast CGI) and PHP 5. The 1and1 server support team are rather vague when answering questions so unfortunately I do not have any useful information from my host.

I've tried doing my own research. I came across the [AddHandler Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) which may be some help if I used it in my root .htaccess file. But I am not sure if that will resolve the problem?

What do these errors mean and how can I resolve them?

Comment: Sounds like some sort of monitoring software. Check your crontab.

Comment: @JennyD actually looking through the whole log file (last 3 days) it is a little more random than every 5 minutes so I doubt it's a scheduled task? It seems to have only been every 5 minutes for the past 30 minutes or so. What do the errors mean?